# Start magnifier minimized in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, magnifier

When I click Windows key and +, it also spawns the magnifying window. How can I set it to start minimized so it's not in the way?

[image: Always have to minimize it away after starting the magnifier]

Comment: Please explain your problem, it is very vague.

Comment: I don't know how I can be more specific. When I click windows key and plus on the keyboard, aka start the magnifier, the window in the picture above appears on the screen. It gets in the way, I always have to minimize it. Is there a way to start the magnifier without the window appearing? I know the hot keys, I don't need the window, just the functionality of zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Regedit.exe and go to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ScreenMagnifier

Create/Set DWORD value data for `MagnifierUIWindowMinimized` to 1

Right-click `ScreenMagnifier` key, click Properties, Advanced.

By default the key is owned by `SYSTEM`. [Take ownership of the registry key](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-of-registry-keys-and-assign-full-permissions/).

After changing ownership, click Apply.

Click Add, Select a principal. Type in your user name.

In the "Type:" drop down box, select "Deny"

Click "Show advanced permissions"

Place a checkmark near `Set value` and `Delete` entries.

Click OK and give your consent when prompted.

Click OK, OK to close the dialog boxes.

Start Magnifier. It should start minimized everytime.

Note: Before denying yourself write access to Magnifier settings registry key above, first make sure you configure Magnifier as needed.